# how to use kmeans to perform clustering of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, k-means, numpy-ndarray

i am trying to cluster my data to using kmeans. I am trying to do this for my array that looks like this:

```
[[11  7  6 ...  0  1  0]
 [ 6  7  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [17  5  3 ...  0  1  0]
 ...
 [ 8  5  1 ...  1  2  0]
 [13  5  0 ...  0  1  0]
 [ 5  1  0 ...  0  2  0]]
```

my array is 2 dimentional, has shape=(588, 26)and the size is 14288

the code that i have been running is:

```
number_of_clusters = 3
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=number_of_clusters, init='k-means++', n_init=5, max_iter=3000,
                verbose=True, tol=0.000001, random_state=123456)
x = kmeans
x.fit(all_termdoc)

y_kmeans = est.predict(my_array)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(my_array[:, 0], my_array[:, 1], c=y_kmeans, s=50, cmap='rainbow');
ax.set_title('Estimated Clusters')


print(y_kmeans)
```

it does return a graph but only with about 10 plots with no apparent clusters. the thing i want to know is if my code is right? thanks in advance!

Comment: please give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)